# Locating indices with element 1 and converting to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an array `A`. I want to identify all indices with element 1 and print as a list. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
A1=np.where(A[0]==1)
A1.tolist()
print(A1)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A1.tolist()

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 2, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A1 = [i for i,x in enumerate(A[0]) if x == 1]
```

or

```
A1=list(np.where(A[0]==1)[0])
```

You have an array inside an array hence A[0]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to find indices where condition is `True` (array elements that are non-zero):

```
res = np.argwhere(A[0] == 1).T
```

---

```
[[0 2 3 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is at the zeroth index of the tuple, so do
`[A1[0].tolist()]` and you will have your expected output.

Comment: Still I don't get the expected output.

Comment: @isaacmodi123 I eddited, does it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have a 2 dimensions array, so the function returns a tuple of array for each dimension. Still, this does not bring your desired output.

There 2 possible ways to achieve this, a classic version and the numpy version - which based on your input data (0 and 1) can be done with `nonzero` method:

```
# the classic version
A1 = [idx for idx, v in enumerate(A[0]) if v == 1]

# the numpy version
A1 = np.nonzero(A[0])
```

The `nonzero` can also be used to apply a different condition to get the indexes, let's say equal to 2.

```
np.nonzero(A[0] == 2)
```

You can read more about the `nonzero` use cases here: [numpy.nonzero doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero).